# smartctl reports different sectors for the first error location

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I'm testing an old HDD, and can't quite understand the output of `smartctl` regarding disk self-tests:

```
$ sudo smartctl -d sat -x /dev/sdd
...
SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9691         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      9691         7948857160
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9687         7948857160
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       113         -
...

$ sudo smartctl -d sat -a /dev/sdd
...
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9691         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      9691         3653889864
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9687         3653889864
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       113         -
...
```

What's the difference between sectors reported by `smartclt -a` and `smartctl -x`?

Comment: It might be a known issue (firmware bug) in some specific disk models... but you didn’t tell the disk model. Otherwise, probably only the manufacturer of the disk could answer that question.

Comment: @telcoM it's a WD_Elements_2620, though I'm surprised that `LBA_of_first_error` is not in fact the first sector with an error discovered in a test, but something manufacturer-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number returned from `smartctl -a` is simply the correct LBA getting truncated to 32 bits. Don't use `smartctl -a` on large disks.
`smartctl -a` per the manpage retrieves the SMART self-test log while `smartctl -x` retrieves the SMART *extended* self-test log. The extended self-test allows longer logs and accommodates a 48-bit LBA. The regular self-test log only supports a 32-bit LBA field. This means `smartctl -a` really ought to never be used for drives bigger than 2TiB.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with 4TB Western Digital Red (WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0) using smartctl (smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-13-amd64]).

I have a single bad block on the drive, reported by SMART monitoring.

`smartctl -a /dev/sdc` *reports 3424096344*

whereas:

`smartctl -x /dev/sdc` *reports 7719063640 (this is the value reported by OpenMediaVault SMART monitoring)*.

Looking at the binary for these values:

```
7719063640: 0001 1100 1100 0001 0111 1001 0000 0101 1000

3424096344:      1100 1100 0001 0111 1001 0000 0101 1000
```

You can see that the binaries match apart from the top nibble. Possibly an int32 versus int64 issue.

However, not clear if this is the drive or the smartctl tool.

The correct value is 7719063640 of course. I used this value and the excellent guide at https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

to re-write the block and clear the SMART error the drive was reporting.